# Ionic cordova iOS 11 HTML audio component broken

Tags: ios, angular, cordova, audio, ionic-framework

i try to get the html5 audio working on ios with cordova.

```
<audio controls> 
     <source [src]="attachment.audioUrl" type="audio/mpeg"> 
</audio>
```

Working fine on Android or on all Web Browsers using ionic serve (Safari/Chrome, no problem). But get stuck on ios. Audiofile is played just once and during playback it says "Live broadcast". When finished, there is no way to get this file play another time but close the view and go back works fine.

Could this be an cordova issue or am I doing something wrong? I already tried different audio types and made sure, that they are correctly formatted. All working on other platforms but ios.

I am using cordova 8.0.0
and ionic 3.20.0

Thanks,

Karsten